# Hide "Change the Look" Menu Item

Tags: 2013, theme, settings, brand, menu

In the "Cog" wheel settings menu, how can I remove the item "Change the look" for everyone? I tried the following CSS with no success:

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Customization_RptControls_Theme {
    display:none;
}
```

I can hide it by ID, but the ID changes depending on where you are, so this is no good

```
#mpl_0_7_Anchor {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery would even be acceptable but I have no success targeting the span element:

```
$("span:contains('Change the look')").hide();
```

Am I close?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS "ends-with" functionality `[attribute$=value]` ([documented here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp)).

Something like this (if the element is a `div` ):

```
div[id$="PlaceHolderMain_Customization_RptControls_Theme"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using jQuery

```
$('[Title="Select a style which defines the fonts and colors for this site."]').hide();
```

Comment: This would only work in an english site though!

Comment: That doesn't work. It's not the Title of the element. Also tried
$('[Title="Change the look"]').hide();
and
$('[Title="Change the look"]').parent().hide();